# Button outside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to build a delete animation like on the iOS Homescreen for my App.
I'm having a collection view and a button. But currently the button is stack inside the cell.

The first image shows my current status, the second one what I want to receive.

[image]
[image]

I set clipsToBounds for the button to false and for the cell and the collectionview to true and x and y for the Button to -10 but the button is cut off. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: you need to set constraint on this button , constraint should be like top and right should be in side of image like 10 pixels

Comment: set `clipsToBounds` on the cell to false.. it seems that the cell cuts the button

Comment: I approve, clipsToBounds should be false for the cell.

Comment: Thanks it works for me

Comment: Any ideas how to get the button to the front?
The button is behind the border. I tried to set cell.bringSubview(toFront: cell.buttonDelete) but nothing happens...I also tried to set the zIndex to 1 but also nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `clipsToBounds` to false so that the cell won't cut out the button.

Comment: Any ideas how to get the button to the front? The button is behind the border. I tried to set cell.bringSubview(toFront: cell.buttonDelete) but nothing happens...I also tried to set the zIndex to 1 but also nothing happens

Comment: you mean the orange border of the cell itself?

Comment: Yes, the cell is on foreground and cuts trough the button

Comment: how do you create that border?

Comment: Yes I set the border in cellForItemAt

Comment: but how do you set it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158161/discussion-between-philipp-rosengart-and-milan-nosa).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have uncut button - you need to set clipToBounds to false. But the part of the button which is located outside of the cell will not react to touch.

It is better to make a cell with enough space for entire button.
For example: make margins for square displaed above.